# How do I determine the status of a specific service?

Tags: windows-services

I'd like to run a command that will give me the status of a specific windows service.  Using sc query, I was able to get this information, see below.

C:\Windows\System32>sc query "IBM Cognos"

SERVICE_NAME: IBM Cognos

```
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    STATE              : 1  STOPPED
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1077  (0x435)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

The only bit of information that I really need to access is the "STATE".  Can I filter the output so I am only seeing the STATE or "1 STOPPED"?  I was hoping I could do something like:

sc query[STATE] "IBM Cognos"

My ultimate goal is to run a .bat file that will output the status of a service to a file.  I can then read that file from another program and use that value to determine whether I should display a green icon indicating "started" or a red icon indicating "stopped" to the user in the UI.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
sc query "IBM Cognos" | find "STATE"
```

Should return something like:

```
    STATE              : 1  STOPPED
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Jeff:  if it works, and it's what you want, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to this answer.

Comment: Sorry, first time here.  Thanks again for your help.